# how to find the character of the series: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{-n^{3}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I Can't see where the series goes.

The series is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{-n^{3}}$$

What criterion can I use?

Comment: Do you see $\sum_{n\geq 1} 2^{-n^3}$ (or just $\sum_{n\geq 1}2^{-n}$)  is obviously convergent?

Comment: merely as a remark on proper wording, the syntagm *nature of the series* is more appropriate then *character of the series* and is part of the habitual parlance of analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root test shows
$$\lim_\infty\sqrt[n]{\left(\dfrac{n+1}{n}\right)^{-n^3}}=\lim_\infty\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{-n^2}=e^{-\infty}=0<1$$